# Class scope vs module scope attributes in Python

Tags: python

I declare a class that does some computations using several hard-coded constants that are defined as class attributes. All of the methods look similar to the following:

```
class IAPWS_1995:
    @staticmethod
    def dAr_ddelta(delta, tau, Delta, theta, psi):
        _dAr_ddelta = \
            sum(IAPWS_1995.n_0 * IAPWS_1995.d_0 * pow(delta, IAPWS_1995.d_0-1) * pow(tau, IAPWS_1995.t_0)) + \
            sum(IAPWS_1995.n_1 * exp(-pow(delta, IAPWS_1995.c_1)) * (pow(delta, IAPWS_1995.d_1-1) * pow(tau, IAPWS_1995.t_1) * (IAPWS_1995.d_1 - IAPWS_1995.c_1*pow(delta, IAPWS_1995.c_1)))) + \
            sum(IAPWS_1995.n_2 * pow(delta, IAPWS_1995.d_2)*pow(tau, IAPWS_1995.t_2) * exp(-IAPWS_1995.alpha_2*(delta-IAPWS_1995.epsilon_2)**2 - IAPWS_1995.beta_2*(tau-IAPWS_1995.gamma_2)**2) * (IAPWS_1995.d_2/delta - 2*IAPWS_1995.alpha_2*(delta-IAPWS_1995.epsilon_2))) + \
            sum(IAPWS_1995.n_3 * (pow(Delta, IAPWS_1995.b_3)*(psi + delta*IAPWS_1995.dpsi_ddelta(psi, delta)) + IAPWS_1995.dDeltab_ddelta(delta, Delta, theta)*delta*psi))
        return _dAr_ddelta
```

The class scope qualifiers makes the code (even more) difficult to read. I had thought of doing something like this to make the code more readable:

```
...
_ = IAPWS_1995
_dAr_ddelta = \
    sum(_.n_0 * _.d_0 * pow(delta, _.d_0-1) * pow(tau, _.t_0)) + \
...
```

If I move the constant declarations to the module scope, though, I don't need scope qualifiers at all.

Is there a reason to prefer declaring the constants in the class over the module (e.g. namespace collisions if I have a similar class `IAPWS_2014` in the future?)

Comment: Are you using the class for anything other than grouping related constants together? Your function looks like it should be declared as a static method, as the first argument is not an instance of `IAPWD_1995`.

Comment: The class groups the related constants and functions together. Everything should be static--there is no state.

Comment: Since your class has no instances, I think making it a module would make more sense. The constants would be module-level variables, and would be accessed as globals by the functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another approach is to simply create a module called `IAPWS_1995`, since you aren't actually instantiating objects from the class. Your module would look something like:

```
n_0, n_1, n_2, n_3 = ...
d_0, d_1, d_2 = ...
t_0, t_1, t_2 = ...
c_1, = ...
b_3, = ...
alpha_2, beta_2, gamma_2, epsilon_2 = ...
dpsi_ddelta = ...
dDeltab_ddelta = ...

def dAr_ddelta(delta, tau, Delta, theta, psi):
    _dAr_ddelta = (
        sum(n_0 * d_0 * pow(delta, d_0-1) * pow(tau, t_0)) +
        sum(n_1 * exp(-pow(delta, c_1)) * (pow(delta, d_1-1) * pow(tau, t_1) * (d_1 - c_1*pow(delta, c_1)))) +
        sum(n_2 * pow(delta, d_2)*pow(tau, t_2) * exp(-alpha_2*(delta-epsilon_2)**2 - beta_2*(tau-gamma_2)**2) * (d_2/delta - 2*alpha_2*(delta-epsilon_2))) + \
        sum(n_3 * (pow(Delta, b_3)*(psi + delta*dpsi_ddelta(psi, delta)) + dDeltab_ddelta(delta, Delta, theta)*delta*psi)))
        return _dAr_ddelta
```

with the constants as module-level variables, and the class method a module-level function.

Other code could use it like this:

```
import IAPW2_1995

x = IAPW2_1995.dAr_ddelta( arg1, arg2, arg3, arg4, arg5 )
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have a similar (maybe modernized) class in the future, e. g. `IAPWS_2014`), it makes sense to consider using a classmethod instead of a staticmethod:

```
class IAPWS_1995(object):
  n_3 = 123
  ...  # further class data

  @classmethod
  def dAr_ddelta(c, delta, tau, Delta, theta, psi):
    _dAr_ddelta = \
        sum(c.n_0 * c.d_0 * pow(delta, c.d_0-1) * pow(tau, c.t_0)) + \
        sum(c.n_1 * exp(-pow(delta, c.c_1)) * (pow(delta, c.d_1-1) * pow(tau, c.t_1) * (c.d_1 - c.c_1*pow(delta, c.c_1)))) + \
        sum(c.n_2 * pow(delta, c.d_2)*pow(tau, c.t_2) * exp(-c.alpha_2*(delta-c.epsilon_2)**2 - c.beta_2*(tau-c.gamma_2)**2) * (c.d_2/delta - 2*c.alpha_2*(delta-c.epsilon_2))) + \
        sum(c.n_3 * (pow(Delta, c.b_3)*(psi + delta*c.dpsi_ddelta(psi, delta)) + c.dDeltab_ddelta(delta, Delta, theta)*delta*psi))
    return _dAr_ddelta
```

This way the newer version of this class can inherit the old one and just override the variables which actually have changed.  If the computation has *not* changed, this must not be implemented anew:

```
class IAPWS_2014(IAPWS_1995):
  n_3 = 1234
  ...
```

A nicer side-effect concerning your original question is that you can name the parameter for the class whatever you like.  `cls` might be typical (and is canon according to PEP8), but `c` works as well and abbreviates the code as with your `_` version.

Comment: For [PEP-8 conformance](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#function-and-method-arguments), the first argument should be `cls`.

Comment: Right.  Will state that more fiercely in the text ;-)

Comment: I think that in this particular case, deriving from the `IAPWS_1995` class to implement a newer standard would violate the open/closed principle: any change to the constants defined in the base class (even though they should not change) would modify the behaviour of the derived class.

Comment: Which could be intended, depending on the change.  In case there was a simple typo in the base class, you won't have to fix it in two places.